# symfony simple-phpunit error 'You have requested a non-existent service "test.client"' only in deployment script

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit, php-7.2, symfony-flex

PHP: **7.2.7**

SYMFONY: **3.4.12**

PHPUNIT-BRIDGE: **4.1.1** (phpunit 6.5.8)

---

I have a deployment script written in PHP that runs as the root user and, since upgrading to php 7.2 from 7.0 and updating my code accordingly, it has begun failing inexplicably when running the phpunit tests. I'm sure I am at fault here, but I have gotten nowhere after many hours of debugging and hope someone might be able to point me in the right direction.

The script runs as root, and when it executes the following:

```
exec("runuser MY-USER -c 'bin/simple-phpunit'", $output, $returnCode);
```

All of my tests fail with:

```
You have requested a non-existent service "test.client"
```

There are lots of SO issues about this error, and it related to the phpunit environment not being set to "test".  My phpunit.xml uses the proper value:

```
<env name="APP_ENV" value="test" />
```

The crazy part is that the unit tests run just fine when I run them myself (as MY-USER).  They even run properly when I log in as root and execute

```
runuser MY-USER -c 'bin/simple-phpunit'
```

They *even* run when I do

```
$ sudo su
$ php -a
php > exec("runuser MY-USER -c 'bin/simple-phpunit'", $output, $returnCode);
```

And when I got desperate and started dumping variables to the console, it seems that everything is proper:

```
echo "ENV = " .getenv('APP_ENV');  // [OUTPUT BELOW]
```

---

```
ENV = dev
```

---

```
exec('bin/console debug:container test.client -e test', $output, $return);
var_dump(implode("\n", $output));  // [OUTPUT BELOW]
```

---

```
Information for Service "test.client"
=====================================

---------------- ---------------------------------------
Option           Value
---------------- ---------------------------------------
Service ID       test.client
Class            Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Client
Tags             -
Public           yes
Synthetic        no
Lazy             no
Shared           no
Abstract         no
Autowired        no
Autoconfigured   no
```

---

```
exec("runuser arderyp -c 'bin/simple-phpunit --debug'", $output, $return);
var_dump(implode("\n", $output));  // [OUTPUT BELOW]
```

---

```
# Everything fails in the same fashion as below
8) App\Tests\Authentication\Security\SomeTest::testSomething
Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException: You have requested a non-existent service "test.client".
```

Before running the tests I properly parse my .env using the symfony standard approach:

```
$dotenv = new Dotenv();
$dotenv->load('.env');
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, it looks like I too was bit by this change in PHPUnit: https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/2353

Adding the `force="true"` attribute to all of my `env` elements resolved the issue.

The problem here is that I am loading (via `Dotenv`) my local `.env` file before getting to this phpunit step.  Without the `force` attribute mentioned above, the environment variables in `phpunit.xml` are not overriding those already set by `.env`.  Consequently, the tests are run with `APP_ENV=dev` instead of `APP_ENV=test`, which causes the `test.client` service to not be recognized, because its only accessible in the `test` environment.  Apparently this is new `phpunit` functionality.  Earlier versions of `phpunit` would allow the variable overriding by default, which explains why I only started experiencing this issue after upgrading PHP (and with it, phpunit).

Comment: Can you give a code example of what adding `force="true"` to your env elements looks like?  Not sure I'm tracking since I've never seen this.  Thanks

Comment: @Jordan, sorry I am late seeing this, but **BEFORE**: `<env name="SYMFONY_PHPUNIT_VERSION" value="7.5" />`  **AFTER** `<env force="true" name="SYMFONY_PHPUNIT_VERSION" value="7.5" />`  (this is from phpunit.xml)